# Tables to word from Matlab

Tags: matlab, vba, ms-word

My code in Matlab, after calculation, prints out the result in word. I am using writetoword.m for this, and my results are mostly in terms of tables. I need help in the alignment of these tables.

```
FileSpec = fullfile(CurDir,[WordFileName,'.pdf']);
    [ActXWord,WordHandle]=StartWord(FileSpec);

WordCreateTable(ActXWord,NoRows,NoCols,readings,6);


function WordCreateTable(actx_word_p,nr_rows_p,nr_cols_p,data_cell_p,enter_p) 


    if(enter_p(1))
        actx_word_p.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment=1;
        actx_word_p.Selection.TypeParagraph;
    end
     actx_word_p.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment=1;

    actx_word_p.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(actx_word_p.Selection.Range,nr_rows_p,nr_cols_p,2,1);

    for r=1:nr_rows_p
        for c=1:nr_cols_p
            actx_word_p.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment=1;
            WordText(actx_word_p,data_cell_p{r,c},'Normal',[0,0]);

            if(r*c==nr_rows_p*nr_cols_p)

                actx_word_p.Selection.MoveDown;
            else 
                actx_word_p.Selection.MoveRight;
            end            
        end
    end

end


function WordText(actx_word_p,text_p,style_p,enters_p,color_p)
    if(enters_p(1))
        actx_word_p.Selection.TypeParagraph;
    end
    actx_word_p.Selection.Style = style_p;
    if(nargin == 5)
        actx_word_p.Selection.Font.Color=color_p;     
    end
    actx_word_p.Selection.TypeText(text_p);
    actx_word_p.Selection.Font.Color='wdColorAutomatic';
    for k=1:enters_p(2)    
        actx_word_p.Selection.TypeParagraph;
    end
    set(actx_word_p.Selection.ParagraphFormat,'Alignment',1);
end
```

I want to print all the tables in a single sheet, and I need tables **side by side**. With the above code it's always starting in a new line. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you considered concatenating the tables which you want side-by-side and then printing them?

Comment: You mean if i have two tables of 2x2 whether i am printing it 2x4?.. Actually thats what i was doing till now.. but i want two seperate tables.. i.e 2 separate tables of 2x2..

Answer (score 0):

When I want two tables side by side in Word I usually start with a new "assisting" table that has the following particulars

- 1 row, 2 columns
- full page width
- no borders
- centered text

Then I write the first table into the left cell of the "assisting" table and the second into the right cell. I also managed to do that from MatLab with a COM-server as you're using it. Some coding is needed but nothing too fancy. If you have questions just let me know.